# jquery dialog open based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am new to JQuery.

My need is, I have few Classroom say 5 classroom, from DB I am getting classroom's.

I am displaying it in format like,

```
Classroom Name    Details
------------------------------ 
classroom 1       Details
classroom 2       Details
classroom 3       Details
classroom 4       Details
classroom 5       Details
```

Now, when person clicks on Details of classroom 1 then dialog should be open which displays details of Students that are part of classroom 1. respective dialog should open for respective classroom.

I am able to open dialog if only 1 details button is there by looking at examples from few links I googled, but my problem is I don't know how many classroom are going to come as it is based on List i will get from DB.

So should I populate my DIV before and on click of details, just to open that DIV as dialog?
What general approach should be for such requirement.

Please don't say what have I tried so for, if it is needed I will paste my code as well. As I took one example from  one link and modifying it to my need.

Can some one please point me some links or help me with sample and explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had meet the similar problem when I use jQuery Dialog. I use jQuery data function to store dialog related data into DOM finally (for your need is the relationship between classroom and detail).

```
var fakeData = [{id:"class1",students:[{name:"student1","tel":"12456"},{name:"student2","tel":"12456"}]},{id:"class2",students:[{name:"student3","tel":"12456"},{name:"student4","tel":"12456"}]},{id:"class3",students:[{name:"student5","tel":"12456"},{name:"student6","tel":"12456"}]},{id:"class4",students:[{name:"student7","tel":"12456"},{name:"student8","tel":"12456"}]}];

//generate detail buttons and store students data in DOM
fakeData.forEach(function(element, index, array){
  $("#btns").append('<button id="'+element.id+'" class="detail-btn">Classroom '+(index+1)+'</button>');
  $("body").data(element.id,element.students);
});

//register click event
$(".detail-btn").click(function(){
    $("#dialog").empty();
    var students = $("body").data($(this).attr("id"));
    students.forEach(function(element,index,array){
        $("#dialog").append("<div>"+element.name+"</div>");
    });
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

I used DOM id attribute to be a unique key of data. And fetch the data when specific detail button is clicked.

You don't have to populate a lot of div in the HTML and just dynamically update the dialog inline content by using this solution.

But I don't know if there is any side effects of this solution until now. Maybe someone can give further explanation.

I make a simple example [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LQS8w/).

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks Chickenrice. your demo example helped me to think modification I need to make for my exact need.